# Reduce the length of whisk in the boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a boxplot and I want to reduce the length of the upper whisk. Is it possible in R?

Comment: This is a question you can answer yourself by searching docs or info on R's specs.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean function `boxplot`, you can modify argument `range`. Note that the notches are not there for fun but relay some information about the values that expand beyond the box part. Do you really need a boxplot? Displaying raw values can be far superior to this visualization that was designed to relay the distribution of points when you only have pen and paper to work with.

Documentation on `range`:

> this determines how far the plot whiskers extend out from the box. If range is positive, the whiskers extend to the most extreme data point which is no more than range times the interquartile range from the box. A value of zero causes the whiskers to extend to the data extremes.